# Git: No match for regexp /diff --git

Tags: git

I've made some changes to my code and I wanted to push to the repository but when I try to `git commit` I get the following exception:

```
  [Gitonomy\Git\Exception\RuntimeException]                                                    
  No match for regexp /diff --git (a\/.*) (b\/.*)\n/ Upcoming: diff --git "a/public/uploads/i  


git:pre-commit [--skip-success-output] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-c|--config [CONFIG]] [--] <command>
```

Any one with an idea how to fix this?

PS: `git add .` works perfectly.

Comment: You had a pre-commit hook which was producing the error. Removing the `.git` folder also removed the hook which would solve the problem. Without knowing what the contents of `.git/hooks/pre-commit` was before you deleted it, it's hard to say what the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by removing `.git` folder and `git init` and `git remote` all over. Not a good move but it fixed the issue however!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do your commit like `commit -m 'your message' --no-verify`

Comment: What does --no-verify do; could you elaborate?